# Rotating an object around a fixed point using glMultMatrix

Tags: opengl, matrix

Rotating an object around (x,y,0) : //2D

```
glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
```

is it correct?!
how about using "glMultMatrix" instead of "glTranslatef" and "glRotatef" ?!

```
glLoadIdentity();
glMultMatrix(Translation_Matrix);      //glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glMultMatrix(Rotation_Matrix);         //glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glMultMatrix(Neg_Translation_Matrix);  // glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
```

is sequence of matrices correct?!

Comment: Just to clear some things up, matrix multiplication is ***applied*** in the same order as written, the difference is that the matrix to be multiplied is put on the other side of the operator. Mathematically, you would usually multiply [OldMat] * [NewMat], but GL does the opposite: [NewMat] * [OldMat] (post-multiplication). This composite multiplication becomes: ***(3rd)*** [Translate -x -y] * [***(2nd)*** [Rotate] * [***(1st)*** [Translate +x +y] * [Original]]]. Everything happens in the same order, but the positions of the operands are swapped and matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since none of the previous answers look entirely correct and complete, let me try:

The key point to understand is that the transformations are applied to your vertices **in reverse order** of the order you specify them in. The last transformation you specify is the first one that is applied to your vertices.

This applies both to using calls like `glTranslate` and `glRotate`, and to using `glMultMatrix`. `glTranslate` and `glRotate` are convenience functions to build specific types of transformations, but they operate just like `glMultMatrix`.

In your example, to rotate around an arbitrary point, you need to first translate your vertices so that the rotation point moves to the origin, i.e. you want to translate by (-x, -y, 0). Then you apply the rotation. Then translate the origin back to the rotation point, which means a translation by (x, y, 0).

Now, since we need to specify these steps in reverse order, this means that your initial set of transformations is in the wrong order. It needs to be:

```
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
```

Your version using `glMultMatrix` looks correct, since you're already specifying the transformations in this order.

Answer (score 1):

> is sequence of matrices correct?!

The order of your first code snippet is correct, the second one though is not. The correct sequence is

```
glMultMatrix(Translation_Matrix);      // glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glMultMatrix(Rotation_Matrix);         // glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glMultMatrix(Neg_Translation_Matrix);  // glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
```

Keep in mind that glTranslate, glRotate and so on boil down to a function the makes a translation/rotation/... matrix and multiplies them using glMultMatrix.

Comment: `glMultMatrix(m1); glMultMatrix(m2); glMultMatrix(m3);` result is : m1.m2.m3.v (Where v is a vertex) m3 is first matrix applied to v

Comment: I think this is backwards. Remember that the last matrix specified is the one that is applied to the vertices first. `Neg_Translation_Matrix` needs to be applied first to move the desired rotation center to the origin, then the rotation, then the translation back to the rotation center. So as far as I can tell, the original poster had the right order, and this one is wrong.

Comment: Well, you fixed the order. But you're still saying that the sequence the original poster used is incorrect, even though it's identical to the one you have now. I added my own answer to hopefully clarify the whole thing.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: The poster has two opposite orders in his question. I'm referring to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming current matrix is ModelView Matrix, and the center of the object is at (x,y,0), the first sequence of translate, rotate, and then translate back seems correct sequence.

When using glMultMatrix instead, I don't think the sequence reverses but they are the same as the first sequence.