# GlRotatef turning object at one point

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to make a door which opens like a normal door.
I thought about using glRotatef but I don't know how to rotate it so it looks like it's swinging.

Current door.class:

```
public static void draw(Texture door) {  

    door.bind();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(-2,3, -15);
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(-2,-3, -15);
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(2,-3, -15);
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(2,3, -15);
    glEnd();

}
}
```

Comment: This answer to a very similar question shows how to rotate an object around an arbitrary point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442499/rotating-an-object-around-a-fixed-point-using-glmultmatrix/23448400#23448400.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define 4 vertices to make the door
2. Rotate the door around the axis pass the right two vertices.

You can calculate the time elapsed totally, and make the door rotate based on the time to make it rotate smoothly.