# 3D rotation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, quaternions, glm-math

So I'm trying to do some rotation operations on an image in openGL based on quaternion information, and I'm wondering, is there a way to define the location of my image by a vector (let's say (001)), and then apply the quaternion to that vector to rotate my image around an arbitrary origin? I've been using GLM for all the math work. (Using C++)

Or is there a better way to do this that I haven't figured out yet?

Comment: Are you sure that you did some research? Googling for [rotation about arbitrary point](https://www.google.com/search?q=rotation+about+arbitrary+point) yields plenty of results.

Comment: At least one search hit is right on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442499/rotating-an-object-around-a-fixed-point-using-glmultmatrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate around a point `P = {x, y, z}` then you can simply translate by `-P`, rotate around the origin and then translate back by `P`.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the transforms should be applied are:

```
scale -> translation to point of rotation -> rotation -> translation
```

So your final matrix should be computed:

```
glm::mat4 finalTransform = translationMat * rotationMat * translationToPointOfRotationMat * scaleMat;
```