# opengl - gltranslatef glrotate error?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I am drawing a cube which I want to move on its own 3 axis (not the ones from the base coordinates). The cube will never be located on the origin, this is why i need to use the glTranslatef() function.

I don't understand:

When I rotate the cube on its y-axis everything goes fine. When I try to rotate it on its x-axis it doesn't work properly: it starts moving accros my screen and doesn't stay on its position.

works fine:
(my cube rotates on its own axis while staying in its own position(0,0.5,0))

```
glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
glRotatef(getCubeAngle(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
glTranslatef( 0.5, 0, 0.0);
```

doesn't work fine:
(cube rotates on its own axis + the cube starts moving over my screen along the x-axis)

```
   glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
   glRotatef(getCubeAngle(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
   glTranslatef( 0.5, 0, 0.0);
/*glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.5, 0.0); with this line instead it works well*/
```

why?

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743207/rotating-around-a-point-different-from-origin/26743386#26743386) about rotating object around different point rather than the origin

Answer (score 0):

Rotation matrices will always use the (current) origin as center for the rotation. When you want to rotate around a different point, you need to translate first, so that the pivot point becomes the local origin.

I don't know what coordinates your cube actually have in object space, So I don't know where exactly the center is.
But from you description one can derive that the center is *not* at (-0.5, 0, 0), which you currenlty use as rotation center. Keep in mind that the order of translatations is *inverted* to what you probably expect. Your code *first* translates by (0.5,0,0) and *then* rotates.

My *guess* would be that your cube is actually already centered at the origin, and you just got the order of transformations backwards.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Well I guess the center is 0,0,0 like always, right? Inverting both translations worked out fine. Thx!

Comment: The center is whatever whoever defined the geomerty for your cube chose as the center.