# Android OpenGL ES 2.0: rotate an object around a specific point

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix-multiplication

I want to rotate an element around a specific point defined by me and dynamically changed.

I am orientating myself at the guidelines from [the google developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html).

My first approach is this:

```
scratch = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
element.draw(scratch);
```

This rotates the object around the center of the screen.

What do I have to add/change to make the object rotate around some other point?

Answer (score 0):

Add a translation operation.

Grafika's [Sprite2d](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/Sprite2d.java) class provides an example:

```
/**
 * Re-computes mModelViewMatrix, based on the current values for rotation, scale, and
 * translation.
 */
private void recomputeMatrix() {
    float[] modelView = mModelViewMatrix;

    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelView, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(modelView, 0, mPosX, mPosY, 0.0f);
    if (mAngle != 0.0f) {
        Matrix.rotateM(modelView, 0, mAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    Matrix.scaleM(modelView, 0, mScaleX, mScaleY, 1.0f);
    mMatrixReady = true;
}
```

This positions the object, then rotates it around the center of the object.

Comment: This still makes the object rotate around the center of the screen.

Comment: Run Grafika, select the "texture from camera" activity.  Touch the screen to set the position, use the slider to set the rotation.  Note the rect is rotating about its own center, not the screen center.  The activity is implemented with the class shown.  If the translation is having no effect, then something else in your code is causing it to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the matrix in the reverse direction of the point first, then rotate and then translate it back. Look at it as if the rotation is always rotating around the center of the world, and the translation moves the center of the world.

Something like this (untested):

```
scratch = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, -x, -y, -z);
Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1f);
Matrix.translateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, x, y, z);
Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
element.draw(scratch);
```

The **x**, **y** and **z** values need to be calculated as the delta between the current position of the object in the world and the position of the point you want to rotate around. You need to do that calculation yourself, but that's pretty trivial.

Comment: This changes the radius of the rotation but it still rotates around the center of the screen.

Comment: This looks like the wrong order of transformations. See for example the accepted answer here for the correct order: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23442499/3530129.

Comment: Now the object flys around the screen in circles while rotating around its own axis... :-)

Comment: Check the answer from @RetoKoradi's link.  We're all sort of guessing at what effect you want, but some combination of translation and rotation should do what you need.