# quad won't rotate around center in lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl

My code is:

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();

// rotate around center
GL11.glTranslatef(-200/2, -200/2, 0);      
GL11.glRotatef(30, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);
GL11.glTranslatef(200/2, 200/2, 0);
// draw quad
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f,0.5f);
GL11.glVertex3f(50,50,1);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0.5f);
GL11.glVertex3f(50+200,50,1);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.5f,0f);
GL11.glVertex3f(50+200,50+200,1);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0f,0f);
GL11.glVertex3f(50,50+200,1);
GL11.glEnd();

GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

and it's not rotating it around the center, am I doing this correctly? if not how would I?

Comment: Wrong order of transformations. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442499/rotating-an-object-around-a-fixed-point-using-glmultmatrix.

Comment: I flipped the order of the transformations but it's still not rotating on the center

Comment: The center of the square you're drawing is at 150/150. So you have to use those values for the amount of translation. Right now you use 100.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, however I was unaware that the x and y position would effect anything.